# converting dsolve output to solve it for a value in sympy

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, differential-equations

I have

```
import sympy as sm

x = sm.symbols('x', cls=sm.Function)
t = sm.symbols('t')
expr = x(t).diff(t) + 0.05*x(t)
sol = sm.dsolve(expr,x(t), ics = {x(0):25})
```

Now i have the solution as an relational equality. Now i want to solve t for x = 1. I can't do
`s = sm.Eq(x,-1)` to do `sm.solve(s,t)` as `s` returns `False`

Comment: It's a bad idea to call the output of dsolve `x` when that's the variable name for the function `x`. Call the output `sol` and then `solve(sol.subs(x(t), 1), t)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out. It's simply easy. x.rhs can be used to create an equation to use solve for t.

```
equation = sm.Eq(sol.rhs,1) 
sm.solve(equation,t)
```

gives the result t ~ 64.38